# LQG with bias rejection for quadcopter attitude control

Tags: control-theory, kalman-filter

We're trying to design an attitude controller for a quadcopter.
The system dynamics are given:
$$ 
\boldsymbol{\dot{q}} = \frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{q} \otimes \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vec{\omega} \end{pmatrix} \\
\dot{\vec{\omega}} = \Gamma_n \vec{n} + \Gamma_u \vec{u} - I^{-1} \left(\vec{\omega} \times I \vec{\omega} \right) \\
\dot{\vec{n}} = k_2 \left(k_1 \vec{u} - \vec{n}\right)
$$
$ \boldsymbol{q} $ is the orientation, expressed as a quaternion, $ \otimes $ is the Hamiltonian quaternion product, $ \vec{\omega} $ is the angular velocity of the drone, $ \Gamma_n $ and $ \Gamma_u $ are constant 3×3 matrices that relate the torque of the motors to the motor speed $ n $ and the motor control signal $ u $. $k_1$ and $k_2$ are constants specific to the motors. $I$ is the inertia matrix of the drone.

We've linearized the system around the equilibrium $ \boldsymbol{q} = (1, 0, 0, 0),\ \vec{\omega}  = \vec{0},\ \vec{n} = \vec{0} $, and we've discretized it using zero order hold. 
This results in system matrices $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$.
The first quaternion state is not independent from the other three quaternion components, so the number of states is reduced from 10 to 9 (remove the first row and column of $A$ and $C$, and remove the first row of $B$ and $D$).
The state $x = \begin{pmatrix} q_1 & q_2 & q_3 & \omega_x & \omega_y & \omega_z & n_x & n_y & n_x \end{pmatrix}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{9×1} $, the output (measurement) $y = \begin{pmatrix} q_1 & q_2 & q_3 & \omega_x & \omega_y & \omega_z \end{pmatrix}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{6×1}$, the input (control) $ u = \begin{pmatrix} u_x & u_y & u_z \end{pmatrix}^T \in \mathbb{R}^{3×1} $.

A full-state LQR controller is used to stabilize the drone, and a Kalman filter is used as an observer.

The first Kalman filter we used is
$$ \hat{x}_{k+1} = A \hat{x}_k + B u_k + L \left(y_k - C\hat{x}\right) $$
For the system with process disturbances $ \delta_x $, input disturbances $ \delta_u $ and sensor noise $ v $:
$ x_{k+1} = A x_k + B u_k + \begin{pmatrix} I_9 & B\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \delta_x \\ \delta_u \end{pmatrix} $
$ y_k = C x_k + D u_k + v $

Then we used MATLAB to calculate matrix $ L $:

```
L = dlqe(A, [ eye(9), B ], C, Q, R);
```

where:$ \quad Q = \mathbb{E}\left(w w^T\right) \quad w = \begin{pmatrix} \delta_x \\ \delta_u \end{pmatrix} \\
 \quad R = \mathbb{E}\left(v v^T\right) $

Now our goal is to add **bias rejection**, in other words, find an observer for the system with constant bias $ d $:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}x_{k+1} \\ d_{k+1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & I_6 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x_k \\ d_k \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} B \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} u_k + \begin{pmatrix} I_9 & B \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \delta_x \\ \delta_u \end{pmatrix} \\
y_k = \begin{pmatrix} C & I_6 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x_k \\ d_k \end{pmatrix} + D u_k + v $$
We need bias rejection, because our measurements for $\boldsymbol{q} $ and $ \vec{\omega} $ are the result of numerically integrating the angular acceleration measurement. On top of that, these measurements are rather temperature sensitive.

We're pretty much stuck, because the pair $ \left(\begin{pmatrix} C & I_6 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & I_6 \end{pmatrix}\right) $ is not observable.

If we only want to estimate the bias on $ \vec{\omega} $, the pair $ \left(\begin{pmatrix} C & 0 \\ & I_3\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & I_3 \end{pmatrix}\right) $ is observable, but MATLAB throws an error when using this system with the `dlqe` command:

```
Error using dlqe (line 91)
(A-G*N/R*C,G*(Q-N/R*N')*G') or (C,A) has non minimal modes near unit circle.
```

Are there any obvious flaws in our reasoning? Is there anything we can do to estimate the bias or drift of our sensor readings?